# Simple boolean if statements printing out y before printing text

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm learning python right now on VS and I'm learning if statements with booleans: here's my code so far:

```
is_toy = False

if is_toy:
    print("YOU ARE A TOY")

else:
    print("you're buzz lightyear!")
```

no matter what the terminal prints out

```
y
YOU ARE A TOY
```

when True or

```
y
you're buzz lightyear!
```

when False,
I'm not sure whether y means yes or if there's some bug or typo

Comment: is this the entire script?

Answer (score 1):

As you've suggested, there's likely a typo somewhere in your code. It's coming from somewhere earlier in your code because there is no way the code snippet you shared would print `y` :)